# How to create empty files in a loop with batch?

Tags: batch-file

I am having a problem on running a script to create empty files in a loop.

This is what have done so far:

```
@echo off
for /l %%a (1;1;20) do (echo m> ".mp4" c:\test)
pause
exit
```

Basically I have twenty names in a file on my desktop and I intend to create them as empty *.mp4 files in folder `c:\test` with the command `echo m> .mp4`. When I run the code above, it does not seem to work.

Comment: You're echoing "m" to a file called `.mp4` 20 times.  If you want to create empty files, try `for /L %%a in (1,1,20) do type NUL >"c:\test\%%a.mp4"`

Comment: thanks rojo, but what if i want to pick names from aonther file in another path and use each name as title of the empty files i make. how do i achieve that?

Comment: If you're saying you have a text file with names, one per line, and you want to create an empty file named line1, line2, etc, then `for /f "userbackq delims=" %%I in ("path\to\textfile.txt") do type NUL >"c:\test\%%I.mp4"`.  If you have a directory full of MP4 files and want to mirror them in a different dir with 0 byte files, then `for %%I in ("path\to\*.mp4") do type NUL >"c:\test\%%~nxI"`

Comment: rojo, you've been a great help, but when i ran this for /f "userbackq delims=" %%I in ("path\to\textfile.txt") do type NUL >"c:\test\%%I.mp4" i got this error message "userbackq delims=" was unexpected at this time." why?

Comment: Ah, sorry.  I had a typo.  Take the `r` out of `usebackq`.

Comment: rojo you are the best mehn. its worked like a charm. cant thank you enough.

Comment: rojo a quick one.i noticed that the script wont pick a word document.but works perfectly with a text document any reason why? can the script me modified to pick a word document ?

Comment: Try opening a Word document with Notepad and you'll see why it won't work.  (Just be careful not to mess up your file associations.)

Comment: @rojo, can you check this script out and help see if you can fix the problem     the subject is - renaming files to a new name folder using batch script

Comment: Sorry, you lost me.  I've never heard of renaming files to a new name folder.  You probably ought to post a new question for this.

Comment: @rojo am also trying to write a script that pick list of names from a text file and use the listed names picked to rename files in a different folder. hope you understand?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following **FOR** loop can be used in the batch file to create empty files `1.mp4`, `2.mp4`, `3.mp4`, ..., `20.mp4` in directory `C:\test` as suggested by [rojo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1683264/rojo):

```
for /L %%I in (1,1,20) do type NUL >"C:\test\%%I.mp4"
```

And the next **FOR** loop can be used in the batch file to read the file names for the empty *.mp4 files to create from a list file on Windows desktop of current user as also suggested by [rojo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1683264/rojo):

```
for /F "usebackq delims=" %%I in ("%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\List of Names.txt") do type NUL >"C:\test\%%I.mp4"
```

For understanding the used commands and how they work, open a command prompt window, execute there the following commands, and read entirely all help pages displayed for each command very carefully.

- `for /?`
- `type /?`

Further the Microsoft article [Using command redirection operators](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490982.aspx) should be read explaining the redirection operator `>` and the SS64 page about [NUL (null device)](http://ss64.com/nt/nul.html).

Comment: you are the best. works exactly the way i wanted it too. thanks a zillion.